# What is the relationship between "Work" fields in Project Server 2007's Reporting Database?

Tags: reporting-services, project-server

The Reporting Database in Project Server 2007 has about 7 "User Views" based on Assignment, Resource, Task, and Project.  They all have fields for Work, OvertimeWork, ActualWork, MaterialWork, BudgetWork, ActualRegularWork.  How do all these fields relate in terms of a formula.  I can't find a good resource on it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this reference from Microsoft Office Online:
[Project: Field Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project/HA102369301033.aspx?pid=CH100788901033)